# Placeholder for images before they are loaded

Tags: reactjs, redux

I display multiple images on the screen and I want to have a placeholder and have small animation for each image while they are being loaded. Once they are loaded completely, I want to display that image instead of that "animation". What I have now is that after the API call is completed to get the items, I `map` through each item and render it on the screen one by one.

```
  const [feedItems, setFeedItems] = useState([]);

  // props from redux state
  const { error, loading, items } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    // dispatch action
    props.fetchItems(0);

    setFeedItems([...items]);

    if (!loading) {
      setLoaded(true);
    }
  }, [setFeedItems]);

  return (
    <div className="items">
      {feedItems.map((item) => <Item key={item.id} item={item} loaded={loaded} />)}
    </div>
  )
```

I do not want to do this. I want to display `Item` component instantly for each item from that feed, but change its `css` class after the image was loaded. As you can see below, make `css` class `item` if image not loaded, and change to `item loaded-item` after loaded.

```
const Item = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={`item ${props.loaded ? "loaded-item" : ""}`}>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

My problem is that I do not know how to achieve this. My `map` function will render components only after the API request was completed. I considered something like the following:

```
<Item key={item?[0]?.id} item={item?.[0]} loaded={loaded} />
<Item key={item?[1]?.id} item={item?.[1]} loaded={loaded} />
<Item key={item?[2]?.id} item={item?.[2]} loaded={loaded} />
.....
```

But for this approach, I will have to add `[loaded]` as dependency for `useEffect` hook, to keep changing images after they loaded, but this will make a lot of continuous API requests (else page does not rerender and images do not change). And considering that I will display like 15 items and will have to do it 15 times, and add pagination as well when the user scroll down to display another 15 items, I believe the code is going to be a complete mess. Could anyone please help with some better solutions for how to achieve here what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a fixed number of placeholder items when the component is in the loading state.  I have used this approach with infinite scroll loading.

Note that the placeholders won't have an `item.id` to use as the `key`, so once the items finish loading the placeholders will unmount and new `Item` components for the actual items will mount.  It won't be the same component instances.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  // props from redux state
  const { error, loading, items } = props;

  // update this, or import from some global constants file
  const PER_PAGE = 12;

  // the page to request - maybe it comes from redux
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  // fetch next items when the page changes
  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchItems(page);
  }, [page]);


  // call this on a button click or a scroll event
  const loadNext = () => {
    setPage(current => current + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div className="items">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item key={item.id} item={item} loaded={true} />
      ))}
      {loading && // show placeholders after loaded items when loading
        Array.from({ length: PER_PAGE }).map((_, i) => (
          <Item key={i} item={undefined} loaded={false} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard about [React Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html#using-suspense-in-practice)?

This might be the answer for your question, it should placehold your image spot while you load the real image.
However your data fetching must be compatible with it, take a look at their first [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-hermann-bztrp).